# 404 Not Found calling Http Method from JavaScript in ASP

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I've looked at a couple of threads now where they want to call a C# method from JavaScript in an ASP project. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here is my C# class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Selfservice.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public String GetCredentials()
        {
            return User.Identity.Name.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the JavaScript I'm trying to call:

```
window.onload = function () {
    LiveSearch();
    getCredentials();
    //FetchAllUsers();
};

function getCredentials() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCredentials", "Home")',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf­8',
        data: JSON.stringify(""),
        success: function (cred) {
            alert(cred);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

I keep getting a 404 Not Found status back. It's an ASP site that's deployed on an IIS, on one of my workplaces servers. We are using Windows Authentication, so I'd like to get the credentials of whoever is logged in and store it for something else later.

I'm kind of at my wits end here. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Easy, you have declared `[HttpGet]` on your action method, while you `POST` to it from jQuery...

Comment: @kayess I'm no JS wiz, but some of the answers I looked at said that was the answer to the problem. Switching to "Get" doesn't fix this.

Comment: did you tried just "/Home/GetCredentials" as url? also like mentioned change to GET remove the contentType and change dataType to "text" as your controller is not returning json

Comment: @kayess Comment is the solution. Simply change `[HttpGet]` to `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: @Kris That seemed to do the trick for a get request at least. Thanks dude. Make it an answer an I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you just tried to reach "/Home/GetCredentials" as URL? Also like mentioned, change to GET method, remove the `contentType` and change `dataType` to "text" as your controller is not returning JSON.

Comment: Actually I tried his solution, which didn't do anything.